# What's infinte sum of the reciprocal of the primorial?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, primorial

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{p_n\#} = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2\times3}+\frac{1}{2\times3\times5}+\dots$$

where $p_n\#$ is the nth Primorial.

Does this sum approaches some known value or constant and do they have a name for it?
I'm also interested in the value for the alternating series which is

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{p_n\#} = \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2\times3}+\frac{1}{2\times3\times5}-\dots$$

I have tried finding it in google but nothing seems to pop up. If so I would like to see this calculated to a few decimal places , because I can't find a program to find the an infinite sum base on primorial.

Edit: Is there any literature,papers or study of these 2 series and similar to these series ?

Comment: The decimal expansion of the first constant has a record in OEIS: https://oeis.org/A064648. There is no special name for it. I haven't found anything about the second constant, either.

Comment: [See also](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-gazette/article/div-classtitle9929-on-the-sum-of-the-reciprocals-of-the-primorialsdiv/56ECB260FAE52588FCECE9AAAAB2695D)

Comment: And the second number is here: https://oeis.org/A132120

Comment: [both are irrational](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1864796/276986)

Comment: I guess the calculation was done numerically anyway, so we could as well calculate it with , lets say , PARI/GP since the sum converges quickly. I am however astonished that someone tried to show the irrationality and moreover actually had success since such proofs usually are extremely difficult or even out of reach.

Comment: This feels like the kind of thing that would be related to the Riemann zeta function.

Answer (score 0):

In general, $\forall (a_n)_{n \geq1}, \text{with } \forall n \geq 1, a_n \in [\![0,p_n-1]\!],$ $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{p_n\#} = \frac{a_1}{2}+\frac{a_2}{2\times3}+\frac{a_3}{2\times3\times5}+\dots \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{p_n-1}{p_n\#}=1$$(telescopic sum).

Let's prove that $S:=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{p_n\#}\notin\mathbb Q$:

Suppose that $S=\frac{a}{b}$, with $a\in \mathbb N$ and $b \in \mathbb N.$

Let $k$ such that $\frac{b}{k}<1\color{red}{(*)}$. Then $bp_k\#S=b\sum_{n=1}^k\frac{p_k\#}{p_n\#}+b\sum_{n>k}\frac{p_k\#}{p_n\#}\color{red}{(**)}$.

We have : $\forall n, p_n \geq n$.

So, $\sum_{n>k}\frac{p_k\#}{p_n\#}=\frac{1}{p_{k+1}}+\frac{1}{p_{k+1}\times p_{k+2}}+...\leq \frac{1}{k+1}+\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}+...=\frac{1}{k}$.

So, from $\color{red}{(*)}$ and $\color{red}{(**)}$, we draw a contradiction.

Q.E.D.

In [primorial numeral system](https://oeis.org/wiki/Primorial_numeral_system), $S$ is noted $(0,1:1:1:1:1:1:...)$

$\color{red}{\text{Theorem : }}(0,1:1:1:1:...)\notin \mathbb Q.$