# Closed form of $\sum \frac {1}{p_1.p_2.….p_r}$ where $p_r$ is the $r^{th}$ prime

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, closed-form

Following is an infinite series quite analogous to the exponential series, but composed of prime numbers only.
$$\frac {1}{2} + \frac {1}{2.3} +\frac {1}{2.3.5} + \frac {1}{2.3.5.7} + \frac {1}{2.3.5.7.11} + …… ≈ 0.70523$$
How can we express it in closed form i.e. how can it be expressed as a combination of known constants (like $π, e,$ etc.) and/or special functions? The only pattern I can conceive is that the denominators form a part of Euclid's proof for infinite primes.

Comment: The product of consecutive primes is called primorial numbers. Maybe this will be helpful? https://oeis.org/A064648

Comment: Primorials grow pretty fast. So even if you do not have a closed form, you can get a pretty good idea of how many terms you need to compute this within machine epsilon.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2117676/whats-infinte-sum-of-the-reciprocal-of-the-primorial

Comment: Although computational methods give exact numerical values yet a closed form is mathematically more meaningful as it tells a lot about the nature of the number, related properties and identities.

Comment: I am 99.9999999999999% sure this sum wont have a closed form in terms of other known numbers and constant.

Comment: As such it becomes more irresistible to define a new function that will characterise this constant number.