# Infinite sum of inverse of products of successive primes

Tags: number-theory

If we iteratively remove the multiples of the succesive prime numbers from the natural numbers, starting from 2, i.e.,

$1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12,  ...  \rightarrow$

$1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21,  ...  \rightarrow$

$1, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 25,  ...  \rightarrow$

we are consecutively removing fractions

$$\frac{1}{2}, \; \frac{1}{2·3}, \; \frac{1}{2·3·5}, \; \frac{1}{2·3·5·7},\;  ... $$

from the total amount of natural numbers. This suggests that the infinite sum

$$\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{2·3}+ \frac{1}{2·3·5}+ \frac{1}{2·3·5·7}+ ...$$

is equal to 1, but I couldn't figure out a proof for this result. Some references about this particular sum would be appreciated too.
Thank you in advance

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2117676/whats-infinte-sum-of-the-reciprocal-of-the-primorial.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the case:
$$\frac12+\frac1{2\cdot 3}+\frac1{2\cdot 3\cdot 5}+\frac1{2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7}+\frac1{2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot11}+\cdots \le  \frac12\left(1+\frac1{3}+\frac1{3^2}+\frac1{3^3}+\frac1{3^4}+\cdots \right)=\frac34$$

It seems that your series converges to
$$0.70523017179180096514743168288824851374357763910915432819226791381\ldots$$
and does so way faster than the geometric series used in the above comparison.
After all, the $n$th summand is $$\le \frac12\cdot\frac{2^n\cdot n!}{(2n)!}\approx \frac{2^nn^ne^{-n}\sqrt{2\pi n}}{2\cdot(2n)^{2n}e^{-2n}\sqrt{4\pi n} }=\frac1{2\sqrt 2}\cdot \left(\frac e{2n}\right)^n.$$

Comment: I see, thank you! I just can't see now where my approach failed, as it seems to make sense. I will think further about it

Answer (score 0):

The denominators are called primorials, the series have been studied and proved irrational in [this article](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-gazette/article/abs/9929-on-the-sum-of-the-reciprocals-of-the-primorials/56ECB260FAE52588FCECE9AAAAB2695D).