# Injectivity of the factorial-related map $f:\mathscr P(\Bbb N) \to \Bbb R$, $f(I) = \sum_{n \in I} \frac 1 {n!}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, factorial, transformation

**Note: For the purpose of this question, $\Bbb N$ does not include $0$.**

I have a function $f:\mathscr P(\Bbb N) \to \Bbb R$ defined by:
$$f(I) = \sum_{n \in I} \frac 1 {n!}$$

This is essentially a transformation from binary sequences indexed by $\Bbb N$ to a number in $\Bbb R$.

I would like to prove that this function is injective.

Comment: Do you mean injective, rather than bijective? It is certainly not bijective onto $\Bbb R$, as $f(I) \geq 0$ for all $I$, nor is it bijective onto $[\min f, \max f] = [f(\emptyset), f(\Bbb N)] = [0, e - 1]$, as it does not contain any element in $(f(\Bbb N - \{1\}), f({1})) = (e - 2, 1)$.

Comment: @Travis Yes, I meant injective.

Comment: BTW this is a special case of factorial expansion (an, in turn, a special case of Cantor series) mentioned - for example - in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1864678/are-there-any-natural-proofs-of-irrationality-using-the-decimal-characterization/1864796#1864796).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** First prove that $f(\{k\}) > f(\{k + 1, k + 2, \ldots\})$ for all $k \in \Bbb N$.

Then, consider distinct elements $I, J \in \mathscr{P}(\Bbb N)$ and the smallest $k \in \Bbb N$ which is in one and not the other. (You'll probably also want to use the apparent fact that $f$ is monotonic under inclusion, that is, that if $I \subseteq J$ then $f(I) \leq f(J)$.)