# What does $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 1/n^n$ converge to?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, limits

Let $0^0 = 1$. 
It can be shown by the inequality introduced below that "my number" $\sum_{n=0}^∞ \frac{1}{n^n}$ is strictly between $2$ and $e$:

\begin{align}
2 & =\frac{1}{0^0}+\frac{1}{1^1} <\text{“my number''}=\frac{1}{0^0}+\frac{1}{1^1}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^3}+\cdots \\[10pt]
& = \frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{27}+\cdots<e=\frac{1}{0!}+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}=\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6}+\cdots
\end{align}
Desmos.com (https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cj1bo9cvfx) shows that this number is equal to approximately 2.291. My questions are:

1. Can this number be expressed by any other way(s) than this one?
2. Is this number rational, algebraic irrational or transcendental?

Comment: $2.2912859970626635404072825905956\ldots$ is closer

Answer (score 3):

This sum is called the [Sophomore's dream](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream)  it can be expressed as an integral. It is not known if the value of the sum is rational, irrational or transcendental. 
$$\int_0^1x^{-x}dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-n} $$
Just add $+1$ if you want to include $n=0$.

Comment: by probability it is closer to be transcendental than any other kind of number :p

Comment: It is [irrational](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1864796/276986) as any convergent series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\prod_{j=1}^n b_j}$ such that any prime $p$ divides some $b_j$ @Masacroso